# Error: no suitable method found for showMessageDialog

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm trying to create a temp conversion from C to F, based on a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` then will display the conversion to the user in a `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`. But I keep getting a no suitable method found error.

Here's the code:

```
package assignment2_2;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Assignment2_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // this program will convert celsius to fahrenheit

        String celsiusInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
            "Enter Temperature in Celsius: " , "Temperature Converter", 
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        double celsius = Double.parseDouble(celsiusInput);

        double fahrenheit = (9.0/5)*(celsius + 32);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, + celsius, 
            " when converted to Fahrenheit is: ", + fahrenheit, 
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

here's the error message:

```
error: no suitable method found for showMessageDialog(<null>,double,String,double,int)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, + celsius, " when converted to Fahrenheit is: ", + fahrenheit, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
method JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component,Object,String,int,Icon) is not applicable
  (actual argument double cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion)
method JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component,Object,String,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component,Object) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
1 error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your position of commas are the problem. It is essentially adding new parameters that shouldn't exist.

Change it to this:

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "" + celsius + " when converted to Fahrenheit is: " + fahrenheit, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful where you put your commas to separate your variables in the method call. When you are adding to a String, you do not need to put commas in between the + signs. Each comma you add tells the compiler that what follows is the next parameter.

In the following:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, + celsius, 
        " when converted to Fahrenheit is: ", + fahrenheit, 
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

You can tell from the warning that the compiler is thinking that you are trying to call

```
showMessageDialog(<null>,double,String,double,int)
```

Because it thinks you are inputting with the spaces it is adding celsius and fahrenheit as doubles instead of adding them to the String.

Once you fix that, you will also need to add a title to the dialog in order to match one of the method calls, or you can remove the `JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE` variable because that is the default and just use the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component,Object)`

This is how you want your method call to look:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, celsius + " when converted to Fahrenheit is: " +
        fahrenheit);
```

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback I took your suggestions regarding the commas and it worked. I never knew about the commas having to match the class but that will definitely help in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your possible methods and parameters

```
public static void showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,
                 Object message,
                 String title,
                 int messageType)
                          throws HeadlessException

public static void showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,
                 Object message)
                          throws HeadlessException

public static void showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,
                 Object message,
                 String title,
                 int messageType,
                 Icon icon)
                          throws HeadlessException
```

You are currenly do this, where I see 4 commas ad 5 arguments.

```
showMessageDialog(null, + celsius, 
        " when converted to Fahrenheit is: ", + fahrenheit, 
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Look at your comma separations, and make sure the method and your parameters match one of the above.